# Smallest and fastest way to capture the output of a forloop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, optimization

I am working on an optimization pass for our asp.net web application and I want to shrink down and speed up as much of the backend as I can.
Is there any way to shrink down a for loop so that it becomes a lambda expression maybe?

A pure example of something that I might want to shrink down:

```
string outS = "";
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
     outS += random.Next(0, 9).ToString();
}
return int.Parse(outS).ToString();
```

Instead of creating a new variable, performing some sort of function to generate it, and then returning it, is there a way where I can do all that in a single line? Like returning a lambda expression function?
Or is the current functionality the fastest way to do it anyway?

Like this silly example:

```
return => for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                random.Next(0, 9).ToString();
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the logic method returns a random number that has a specified number of digits in the length variable, you could do something like this:

```
private int TestMethod(int length) => 
    new Random().Next((int)Math.Pow(10, length - 1), (int)Math.Pow(10, length));
```

This form has some adventages:

1. No string concatenation. String concatenation is not recommended if many concatenations are performed.
2. The number of times a random number is requested is reduced (in the above code, the Random.Next method is only invoked once).

Nevertheless, it's a good practice that you perform a profiler comparing alternatives. You can do it with the Diagnostic Tools View in Visual Studio, and with the [StopWatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netcore-3.1) class

Comment: Although this is useful for something else, I just need a slim fast way to write ANY for loop. The random number was just an example. I just want to know if there's a faster way to write a for loop to directly capture the output

Comment: As a said in programming, "it depends". I don't think there is a general way to write a fastes loop. The context of the loop is particularly important.

Comment: Ah right.. ok. In general, for larger loop situations then I'll just stick with the normal format. Thanks for the random function btw. That is helpful elsewhere.

Comment: Ok. I think there is no generic way to write code that is faster for any scenario. You can write the code in a short way (fewer keystrokes), but writing the code in fewer lines does not mean that the code runs faster (less time complexity) or that the code will make better use of your computer resources (space complexity)

Comment: Yes, I thought so. I would like to directly take the output of a for loop and assign it into a variable or directly return it but that's all good.

Comment: Sure, but the process that is doing inside the loop conditions the result. On the other hand, if you need only the value of a general cumulative loop, you can use the Enumerable.Aggregate method (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=netcore-3.1)

Answer (score 0):

If you're just wondering about condensing lines of code, you can use Linq's `ForEach` method and pass in a lambda expression.

This:

```
string outS = "";
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
     outS += random.Next(0, 9).ToString();
}
return int.Parse(outS).ToString();
```

Becomes this:

```
string outS = "";
new List<int>(10).ForEach(_ => outS += random.Next(0, 9).ToString());
return int.Parse(outS).ToString();
```